# MFMessageComposeViewController substitute full URL link inside SMS body with "clickable" text

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, imessage

Inside the app I have a MFMessageComposeViewController presented with pre-defined text. Inside this text I have a link, for example: "Hey, visit this site https://stackoverflow.com/"

In HTML we can do next:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">site</a>
```

And it will make "site" clickable. Is there any way to do inside the app, so that recipient will receive iMessage with text link, instead of full https://stackoverflow.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMS does not support HTML or URLs, just plain text.

All you can do is just add the URL to message and then it's up to the Message app to recognise the URL and allow the user to click on it.